# Bug with texdef (currfile) in frozen TexLive 2011

Tags: texlive, linux, texdef

To keep in line with the Q&A format:

I am on Ubuntu Lucid, with the frozen TexLive 2011, from where I installed `texdef`. Unfortunately, when I ran one of the examples from the help (and I installed `xspace`) specifically for this, I got:

```
$ texdef -t latex -l -p xspace
:
Compile error: Undefined control sequence.
```

What is the problem?

---

EDIT:

Versions discussed here:

```
$ texdef --version
texdef: Version 1.6 -- 2012/05/02

$ grep -A3 'ProvidesPackage' `kpsewhich currfile.sty`
\ProvidesPackage{currfile}[%
    2012/05/06
    v0.6
    Provides the file path elements of the current input file]
```

Comment: Please report bugs directly to the package/script author using the provided email address in the package manual. This is not a page for bug reports. (Even if the author, here me, is a regular)

Comment: And please provide the version of the script (and `currfile`) you are using. TeX Live 2011 is not an exact description, it's just the distribution. I updated `texdef` (and `currfile`) several times during the 2011 live cycle.

Comment: Hi @MartinScharrer - thanks for the notes; added versions above. Sorry for posting here; but unfortunately when I discover bugs (like this time), I'm usually not in a position to utilize my mail - so I thought I'd better just quickly post something where I can do it quite quickly. (_A bug report page for Latex packages that accepts OpenID would really do the trick for me, I guess_). Apologies again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is fixed in v1.7b from 2012/05/15 available from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texdef) and from the [Bitbucket Mercurial Repository](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/texdef) including a [TDS ZIP file](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/texdef/downloads/texdef.tds.zip) for easy install. There is also a [bug tracker](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/texdef/issues) where issues can be reported. Please ensure that you have the latest released version before reporting issues.

The same is true for `currfile`: [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/currfile), [Bitbucket Mercurial Repository](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/currfile).

Comment: Many thanks for the fix, @MartinScharrer - and apologies again for posting the bug publicly.

Answer (score 3):

Thankfully, `texdef` is a Perl script - so I added a `print $_` to the texpipe, to observe results - and the texing process was crashing at:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.42         \currfile@realmainfilefalse

! Extra \fi.
l.53 \fi\fi
```

Since `texdef` depends on `currfile`, that must be the source of errors - and indeed, there are some mismatching definitions:

```
$ grep -i '20..\|ifcurrfile@abspath' `kpsewhich currfile-abspath.sty`
    2012/05/06
\newif\ifcurrfile@abspath@windows
    \ifcurrfile@abspath@windows
$ grep -i '20..\|ifcurrfile@abspath' `kpsewhich currfile.sty`
    2012/05/06
\RequirePackage{filehook}[2011/01/09]
    \ifcurrfile@abspath
\ifcurrfile@abspath
    \ifcurrfile@abspath
\ifcurrfile@abspath
\ifcurrfile@abspath
\ifcurrfile@abspath
        \@namedef{ver@fink.sty}{2011/01/09}%


$ grep 'ifcurrfile@' `kpsewhich currfile-abspath.sty`
\newif\ifcurrfile@abspath
    \ifcurrfile@abspath

$ grep 'ifcurrfile@' `kpsewhich currfile.sty`
\let\ifcurrfile@realmainfile\relax
\expandafter\ifx\csname ifcurrfile@realmainfile\endcsname\relax
    \ifcurrfile@abspath
\ifcurrfile@abspath
\ifcurrfile@realmainfile
    \ifcurrfile@abspath
\ifcurrfile@abspath
\ifcurrfile@abspath
\ifcurrfile@realmainfile
\ifcurrfile@abspath
\ifcurrfile@fink
```

These two hacks seem to solve the problem:

```
sed -i 's/ifcurrfile@abspath@windows/ifcurrfile@abspath/' `kpsewhich currfile-abspath.sty`
sed -i 's_\\let\\ifcurrfile@realmainfile_\\newif\\ifcurrfile@realmainfile\n\\let\\ifcurrfile@realmainfile_' `kpsewhich currfile.sty`
```

And now I can happily run the example command line:

```
$ texdef -t latex -l -p xspace
Defined by file 'xspace.sty':
\xspace
\xspaceaddexceptions
\xspaceremoveexception
```